# 555 timer emits tone regardless of reset value

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, output, 555

I made a microcontroller circuit on a PCB and I attached a typical timer circuit to it.

The IC of the timer is an 8-pin DIP texas instruments NE555
Resistors are 5% tolerance.
Output capacitor is electrolytic and other capacitor is ceramic

I tried this circuit with the microcontroller and without it attached. (I use a socket to insert my micro in) and I get this issue:

When I don't make the input low (P3.7=high), the output is accurate. But when I ground the input, I expect no sound but instead I get a faint high-pitched sound that I can still hear.

How do I remove the high pitched sound while keeping the correct sound at the same (or at least similar frequency)?

[image: timer]

Comment: Does the LM555N work on the Vcc you are using? The CMOS version might but I thought the original LM555N required a higher voltage.

Comment: If you connect the speaker directly from ground to Vcc (with 4.7uF in series) do you still hear the tone?

Comment: No capacitor on CV input ?

Comment: Its strange. Today I ran the same test with the same parts and everything seems to be functioning normally. Only thing I could guess now is a tiny short circuit in the board that has since been removed. On further inspection, it seems the sound is normal whether the input is floating or to VCC but when grounded, the sound is off.